# Remove double quotes from header in SED

Tags: sed, double-quotes

i would like to remove double quotes from the header row only.  The data below is in a txt file with tab-delimiter. Thanks!

`"$sedol"   "$cusip"    "$rbss_id"`

"2877365"  "22122P101" "53301020"

"B0G72D1"  "         " "50102020"

The desired answer is:

`$sedol $cusip  $rbss_id`

"2877365"   "22122P101" "53301020"

"B0G72D1"   "         " "50102020"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sed:

```
sed '1s/"//g' file.txt
```

`1s` will make sure to replace `"` on line # 1 only.